# Unit Testing Azure Mobile App (Node.js) Locally

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, azure-mobile-services

#### Please don't tell me I should have been testing before now. I don't disagree, and that's not the point of this question. If it helps, assume I'm doing TDD perfectly and I'm asking this question about a brand new project. ;-)

I've been developing an Azure Mobile App with a Node.js backend for some time now. I have done so completely dependent on Microsoft hosting the service (which I think makes sense). Now, though, I'd like to have some unit tests running against my code, but I'm at a loss for how to get from a functional, Microsoft-hosted Azure Mobile App to a locally-hosted version where I can run my tests.

#### A big assumption here is that the testing will run much faster if I'm running them locally. A lot of my code interacts with a SQL Server database, so please tell me if this is an incorrect assumption.

Anyway, I've gotten Node.js and NPM set up on my Mac. I've gone through some basic tutorials on creating a Node.js site from scratch, and I got the ubiquitous "Hello World" Node.js website working locally. I even apparently got a basic Azure Mobile site up and running (at least, I got the "This mobile app has been successfully created" homepage to show up).

I've also done some reading on Mocha and Chai for Unit Testing in Node.js. I even got through some of their first examples and had some simple tests working.

What's confusing me is how to move from the super-basic Mocha test examples to more real-world testing of my actual code.

For instance, here's a Mocha test example (taken from [semaphore](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-js-and-mocha)):

```
var expect    = require("chai").expect;
var converter = require("../app/converter");

describe("Color Code Converter", function() {
  describe("RGB to Hex conversion", function() {
    it("converts the basic colors", function() {
      var redHex   = converter.rgbToHex(255, 0, 0);
      var greenHex = converter.rgbToHex(0, 255, 0);
      var blueHex  = converter.rgbToHex(0, 0, 255);

      expect(redHex).to.equal("ff0000");
      expect(greenHex).to.equal("00ff00");
      expect(blueHex).to.equal("0000ff");
    });
  });

  describe("Hex to RGB conversion", function() {
    it("converts the basic colors", function() {
      var red   = converter.hexToRgb("ff0000");
      var green = converter.hexToRgb("00ff00");
      var blue  = converter.hexToRgb("0000ff");

      expect(red).to.deep.equal([255, 0, 0]);
      expect(green).to.deep.equal([0, 255, 0]);
      expect(blue).to.deep.equal([0, 0, 255]);
    });
  });
});
```

It's no real surprise that this code will fail until `../app/converter.js` is created with the appropriate functions exported. Ok, so I try to adapt that kind of thinking to, say, my `Login` method, and I'm unable to connect the dots.

My `Login` code happens to reside at `../api/Authentication/Login.js` in the file structure. Is that going to matter to my test code, or can I simply reference something like `.post('Login')`? Either way, here's an overview of my `Login.js` file:

```
var auth = require('azure-mobile-apps/src/auth'),
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = {    
    post: function (req, res, next) {
        // Actual code removed
    }
};
```

I have no idea how to construct the `req`, `res`, and `next` variables/parameters. When it comes to this point, an article I read by Michael Herman ([link](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/09/10/testing-node-js-with-mocha-and-chai)) seems to be closer to what I'm trying to do.

In that article, a `test-server.js` file is set up with contents like this:

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var server = require('../server/app');
var should = chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Blobs', function() {
  it('should list ALL blobs on /blobs GET', function(done) {
    chai.request(server)
    .get('/blobs')
    .end(function(err, res){
      res.should.have.status(200);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This seems to be referencing `/blobs` because in `../server/models/blob.js`, there is this line:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('blobs', blobSchema);
```

That's what makes me think that maybe the following lines (in my `Login.js`) are doing something more structured behind the scenes:

```
module.exports = {    
    post:
```

Anyway, this is just the tip of the iceberg. My Azure Mobile App has environment variables and connection strings, etc. Is it possible for me to get all of that running on my local machine, or am I better off to implement my testing in Azure's portal somehow?

If I should do it locally, how can I get that set up?
If I should do it in Azure's portal, how do I begin there?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/01/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-2-local-development/) on how to run Azure Mobile App locally.

Comment: @AaronChen That article was very helpful for getting an Azure Mobile App running locally. Seems to work perfectly. I'm still having trouble getting it to be testable with `mocha`, though. New question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815167/mocha-with-azure-mobile-app-getting-started). If you'll expand your comment into an answer, I'll be glad to accept it for this question. Please take a look at my new question, if you would. Thanks!