# Mocha with Azure Mobile App: Getting Started

Tags: node.js, azure, mocha.js

### tl;dr;

Because of the close vote, I wanted to clarify what I'm asking. I want to know how to go from a functional, local Azure Mobile App with a Node.js backend to one that can be tested successfully with Mocha and Chai. The 3 issues listed below are all hurdles that I see that are keeping me from testing my App Service in this way. There seems to be something extra that is required that makes an Azure App Service different from a standard Node.js web application. I am trying to figure out what those differences are and how to work around them or fix them.

---

#### Intro

I have been working to get a copy of my Azure Mobile App with Node.js backend running locally.

Here are some of the resources I've been using:

- [30 Days of Zumo.v2 (Azure Mobile Apps): Day 2](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/01/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-2-local-development/)
- [Testing Node.js with Mocha and Chai](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/09/10/testing-node-js-with-mocha-and-chai/#.WeZoa3CZOL5)
- [Ensure Express App has started before running Mocha/Supertest tests](https://mrvautin.com/ensure-express-app-started-before-tests/)

I have finally gotten that to work, but I am encountering issues with running Mocha tests against my code.

All is well when I run this:

```
node app.js
```

I get all of the expected outputs (specifically, the API routes added), and my browser can browse my site/API.

When I run `mocha`, however (or `npm test` if I have added that to my `scripts` property), nothing seems to work properly. My initial tests **are** failing, but they're failing because of:

1. timeout issues, or
2. API not created errors (404 errors)

Just for fun, I changed my `test.js` file to only run the following test:

```
describe('Addition', function () {
    it('should add two numbers correctly', function(done) {
        (2 + 4).should.equal(6);
        done();
    });
});
```

It worked exactly as expected, so the issue appears to be with loading up my custom API in my `app.js` file, or some other, Azure-related, non-Node.js-specific issue/error.

---

#### Issue 1:

As I believe is normal for an Azure Mobile App, my `app.js` file loads all of my API (`.js`/`.json` file pairs). Here are the pertinent lines:

```
var mobile = azureMobileApps({
    homePage: true
});
mobile.api.import('./api');
app.use(mobile);
```

When I run the `mocha` command in Terminal, I consistently get the following warning:

```
warn: Requested configuration path 
      (/{path to repo}/node_modules/mocha/bin/api) 
      does not exist
```

This seems to me to be trying to use the `'./api'` reference from the `app.js` file and apply it to the `mocha` "whatever" (script? executable?) that is found here: `/{path to repo}/node_modules/mocha/bin`.

Now, I'm pretty sure I could apple a band-aid fix to this problem by changing this line:

```
mobile.api.import('./api');
```

to this:

```
mobile.api.import('../../../api');
```

So, when I do that, I no longer get the `Requested configuration path does not exist` error, but I also don't get the printout in the console telling me that the API methods were created. Trying with other depths (e.g., `'../api'` or `'../../api'`) gives me the `Requested configuration path does not exist` error, so I think the `'../../../api'` path is the correct one, but it doesn't appear to **do** anything with that path now (when using `mocha`).

---

#### Issue 2:

I'm also not seeing the `verbose: SQL Azure database detected - setting connection encryption` line printed out. This seems to be telling me that my `azureMobile.js` file isn't being loaded when calling `mocha` as it appears to be when calling `node app.js`.

Is there something different that happens for an Azure Mobile App when calling `node app.js` that isn't happening when calling `mocha`? If so, what is it, and how can I get `mocha` to actually act like `node`?

One thought I had was that my `app.js` file has these declarations at the top:

```
var express = require('express'),
    azureMobileApps = require('azure-mobile-apps');
```

I'm obviously using `azureMobileApps` to create the `mobile` variable, which is what is supposed to `.import()` the API files. Is there another pathing issue with how `mocha` loads `app.js` for testing? `express` seems to get loaded OK, so I am doubting that's the issue, but I'm grasping for any and all straws at this point.

---

#### Issue 3

I am trying to make sure that my "site" has time to load everything up before attempting to run tests. To that end, I have attempted to install an `EventEmitter` that will wait for my API to load before beginning my tests.

**This assumes that my `mobile.api.import()` call is asynchronous, which might be a faulty assumption. Also, that call might be failing not due to timing, but due to the `azureMobile.js` issue discussed above.**

Here's the pertinent code:

`app.js`:

```
app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('App has started');
    app.emit('appStarted');
});

module.exports = app;
```

`test.js`:

```
var app = require('../app');
before(function (done) {
    app.on('appStarted', function(){
        console.log('Got appStarted event');
        done();
    });
});
```

Although I see the `'App has started'` message in the console, the `app.on('Started'...` code is never called.

#### Summary

So, in short, while I am able to facilitate local development, I have not yet been able to figure out how to use Mocha to test my local development. Any pointers or fixes for problems shown above are much appreciated!